# Docker CodeIgniter Routes Redirects to Docker IP

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter, ubuntu, docker

I am trying to run a CodeIgniter project inside a Docker Container. My base image is Ubuntu 16.04 in which I have installed a LAMP stack. My container has a Volume mounted from my host machine where my Project Resides. My docker run command is as follows.

```
docker run -ti -v /Users/user/Documents/projects:/var/www/html  -p 80:80 -p 3306:3306 ubuntu
```

The problem is whenever I try to run the project as http://localhost/project/, it is getting redirected to Docker's local Ethernet IP such as 172.17.0.2/project/

But if I test it with a simple phpinfo file, it runs fine.

My Machine : macOS Sierra

Docker Image : Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: have you tried 0.0.0.0/project?

Comment: Still not working :( Same Redirect Issue

Answer (score 2):

Check your apache proxy configuration. Can you change the host_port and again check? 
I'm using nginx `-p 127.0.0.1:80:80`. Check your local ip/ports using `**sudo netstat -plunt**` and also check this 
[sudo iptables -t nat -L -n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDoXj.png)

Comment: Not working. When i was working in linux there seems to be no Issue. But When I am on a mac, the issue exist

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/'` (or whatever fits you) in *config.php*, because if the value is not set it will be as follow (it is written in config file description, right above base_url):

> If it is not set, then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol and path your installation, but due to security concerns the hostname will be set to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.

So I guess you didn't set this value and CodeIgniter used `172.17.0.2` because it is `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`.